# No puedo dejar seleccionada las difentes palabras cuando se selecciona

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Ya cuento con este codigo pero al momento de correrlo se cambia la palabra seleccionada.

```
function MacroCambiarColor() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    var valorCell = cell.getValue();
    var buscar  = "ROJO";  // en mayuscula porque uso toUpperCase()
    var vposini = valorCell.toUpperCase().indexOf(buscar);
    if( vposini > -1 ){

        vposfin = buscar.length + vposini;
        spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
              .setText(valorCell)
              .setTextStyle( vposini, vposfin, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
              .setForegroundColor('#0000ff')
              .setBold(true)
              .build())
              .build());

    }
} // cierra function
```

Comment: Podrias explicarme mejor donde sale el error? .toUpperCase() transforma texto de "Minuscula" -> "MAYUSCULAS" @user333262